# How to write a bash script for set lock-screen time out for different Ubuntu desktops?

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, kubuntu, automation

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and already i have scripted for gnome environment. I need to know that cannot we use a common script for all the Linux desktop environments?

Bellow is my script,

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script has been tested in the Ubuntu 18.04.

MAXIMUM_IDLE_DELAY=300        # maximum session idle valuse for the power management in seconds
MAXIMUM_SCRN_LOCK_DELAY=300   # maximum screen-saver lock delay in seconds
MAXIMUM_DELAY=$(($MAXIMUM_IDLE_DELAY + $MAXIMUM_SCRN_LOCK_DELAY))

IS_ENABLED=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled)
USER_IDLE_DELAY=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay | cut -d ' ' -f2)
USER_SCRN_LOCK_DELAY=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay | cut -d ' ' -f2)
USER_TOTAL_DELAY=$(($(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay | cut -d ' ' -f2) + $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay | cut -d ' ' -f2)))

function screen_lock_Test(){
    if [ "$IS_ENABLED" == "true" ] && [ "$USER_IDLE_DELAY" -gt 0 ];then
        if [[ $USER_TOTAL_DELAY -le $MAXIMUM_DELAY ]];then
            echo "Configurations matching with the given settings" 1>&2
            return 0
        else
            echo "Screen lock settings takes too much time to lock down !!!!!" 1>&2
            return 1
        fi
    else
        echo "Screen lock configurations do not match with the given settings !!!!!" 1>&2
        return 1
    fi
}

screen_lock_Test
echo $?
```

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide the script, people may suggest modifications to make it useful across desktop environments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion DK Bose. the script will check for some configs and return whether the system has those configs. I'll attach it.